# Problem: rack is occupied. Is it possible to remove agents from a racksystem without using them in a flowchart?

Tags: java, anylogic, agent, flowchart, statechart

I am modeling order picking in anylogic: At the moment I create a population of agents and give them to the enter-block via an event. This block is connected with a rackstore block and puts the agents in the racksystem. In a statechart of a person (when the person arrives at the agent location), the agent is taken and put into another enterblock, which is just connected with a sink -> the agent is removed from the racksystem.

Problem: If I want to store agents in the racksystem again, the cells (where agents where before) are occupied. I think the reservation of the cell is not discarded. How can I solve the problem?

Or: Is there a better solution to store and/or remove the agents ? Maybe without using flowcharts at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're removing agents in racks via a `RackPick` block, you aren't actually removing them from the rack system (even if the agent is moving 'past' the `RackStore` block in the process flow). So your process would need to be something like:

- There is a `Wait` block following the `RackStore` (which holds them in the process until required).
- When the "person arrives at the agent location" (your trigger for removing the agent from the rack, though it's not clear what this means --- what is the "agent location" since it's in a rack?), you `free` them from the `Wait` block.
- The `Wait` block is followed by a `RackPick` block which will remove them from the rack.
- The removed agent carries on in whatever the follow-on flow is (which might just be a `Sink` in your case).

**NB**: Also, part of the functionality of `RackStore` and `RackPick` blocks is to use resource agents to move to the rack and deposit/retrieve the agent, so it's likely you don't need a "person agent" to be explicitly moving to the agent location (outside of these blocks), though that depends on the exact specification of what you want your model to do.